# Why isn't my embedded flash player working (c#)?

Tags: c#, flash, video

I'm new to flash player. I think I've nearly figured it out, but it's not working, and I'm at an impasse.

I inserted the object in the form, and I'm using:

```
string path;
string path = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/aHjpOzsQ9YI";
axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, path);
axShockwaveFlash1.Play();
```

I think I have the Youtube address formatted right... but the flash object does nothing. No error. Just nothing. So there's no debugging it to fix it.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the debugger to see what's happening in the LoadMovie() method? Is this a third-party component? If so, what does the "0" parameter do in the LoadMovie() method? I don't think there's quite enough context here to tell what might be going wrong.

Comment: This is for a project in Fundamentals of Programming... we haven't actually learned to use a debugger yet, lol, just assumed if there were no errors it wouldn't help. The 0 is because the tutorial I watched told me to put it there, it said it was so it loads into the first level, the root level... I have that running during the form load so that should already be in place even before the path is set, let alone before it plays.

Comment: Are you using the Designer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Is this what you wanted? Because if it is then you've done everything right.</strike>  (removed screenshot - no longer relevant to question) Perhaps wait a bit and see if it loads. Obviously `AxInterop.ShockwaveFlashObjects.dll` is loading properly as you are not getting 
any null references so the `AxShockwaveFlash` class is being instantiated properly.

Are you sure you are connected to the internet? If so, is it slow?

**Edit per your comment about wanting to autoplay the video:**

Simply add `?autoplay=1` to the URL and it plays on load. You actually don't even need the call to `Play()`.

Here is the final code:

```
string path = @"http://www.youtube.com/v/aHjpOzsQ9YI?autoplay=1";
axShockwaveFlash1.LoadMovie(0, path);
```

Comment: Hrm... I was assigning the address through a tertiary variable assignment, and changed that to be direct, and I got the movie to load, but it won't actually play without clicking the play button on the video. This won't work. I'm using it as a video alarm clock, and it needs to activate based on a time based control I built completely autonomously, because I have to assume that the user is asleep!

Comment: Maybe Flashplayer is just too volatile... I was reading that sometimes the play/stop buttons work and sometimes they don't... maybe I should try vlc? WMP I can get to work, but it doesn't play nice with Youtube. I really don't want to resort to local files, for both storage space and compatibility issues, I'd have to recode the file paths every time I used it on a different computer, eh?

Comment: I THINK that's enough that I can build what I need. Even if it isn't, you answered my question and more, and the rest is on me. Thanks for the help!